# Dual graphics. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, samsung, amd-graphics, dual-graphics

I have a Samsung series 5 notebook (NP510R5e-S05) with dual graphics (Intel HD4000 + and AMD hd8750m). Also Ubuntu 16.04.1 is installed on my laptop. I have a problem with amd card. This card doesn't work. Can you give me advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to install the AMD driver? You can probably find it in the Additional Drivers menu.

Comment: Yes, amdgpu from the website. In additional drivers menu I can see only intel driver. Can I use the fglrx on this ubuntu version? (Sorry for my English)

Comment: Hmm this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD  suggests that fglrx is not supported on 16.04 LTS.

Check out this page, maybe you find something useful.